# How to write a neo4j cypher query to find closed loop of similar nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find if in my database I have a closed loop consisting of only nodes that match certain criteria. I know how to specify a variable number of relationships matching criteria, such as: `-[rel_type:type*]->`, but I can't figure out how to specify the criteria for the nodes I want to have in the variable length path.

I tried this, but it found nodes not matching the criteria:

```
match (n{rel_type:'type'})
match (m) -[*]-> (m)
return m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
MATCH p=(m)-[*]->(m)
WHERE ALL(n IN NODES(p) WHERE n.rel_type = 'type')
RETURN m
```

##### Neo4j 5.9+

Starting with Neo4j 5.9, you can instead use a [quantified path pattern](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#quantified-path-patterns), which may be more efficient:

```
MATCH (m WHERE m.rel_type = 'type') (()-->(n WHERE n.rel_type = 'type')){1,} (m)
RETURN m
```

The above query specifies the node criteria (`rel_type = 'type'`) twice: once for the starting node, and once for the endpoint of every `NEXT` relationship (within the quantified path pattern). This way, all the nodes in matching paths are tested once, and only once (except for `m`, which is tested twice).

Finally, to avoid testing `m` twice you can do this:

```
MATCH (m WHERE m.rel_type = 'type')
MATCH (m) (()-->(n WHERE m = n OR n.rel_type = 'type')){1,} (m)
RETURN m
```

The `MATCH` clause has to be split into 2 clauses here to avoid the error:

> From within a quantified path pattern, one may only reference
> variables, that are already bound in a previous `MATCH` clause.

##### Caveat

Using variable-length paths with unlimited upper bounds on the path length can cause you to run out of memory or take a very long time. If possible, you should put an upper bound on your queries.  For example, to place an upper bound of 8, you can use `[*..8]` (in the first query above) or `{1,8}` (in the second).

Comment: Thank you that seems to work in my test database, unfortunately it's timing out in production. I'll have to see about increasing our timeout.

Comment: I added a Caveat to my answer.